Nuxt 3 fresh app build generate HTML that references JavaScript files from a deleted project
I created a fresh Nuxt application to deploy it to firebase hosting, but when I run npm run build -- --preset=firebase it generate HTML that references JavaScript files from a deleted project.
Steps:

Create nuxt project then run it successfully

npx nuxi@latest init myapp

Follow instructions to deploy Nuxt application to firebase from nuxt official website

Build and run on firebase emulator:
npm run build -- --preset=firebase
firebase emulators:start


I go to localthost:5000, It show my old deleted Nuxt app. Right click - view source, it show HTML of the old project, I found this:
<script type="module" src="/_nuxt/Users/kevin/Documents/testNuxt/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.js" crossorigin>

Which testNuxt is my old deleted project, how can I correct this url?
firebase.json:
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".output/server",
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{ "source": "**", "function": "server" }]
  }
}

nuxt.config.ts:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  nitro: {
    firebase: {
      gen: 2
    }
  }
})

